# Girard's System $F$ (also named Polymorphism)

Tags: notation, proof-theory

I have been studying Girard's Polymorphism and a question came to my mind: why is it (also) called system $F$? Where does the $F$ come from? (i searched it online but didn't get any luck...)

Comment: Maybe Girard called it that because he wanted to? Mathematicians choose symbols all the time - for example, I think that we use $\theta$ because some mathematician thousands of years ago decided that he liked $\theta$ as an angle. Also, Newton choosing $\int$ for integration - why not $\bigwedge$?

Comment: I don't really know about \theta - but Newton's choice makes sense, the symbol is a sort of "nicer" S - where S stands for sum, since that's basically what an integral is!

Comment: True. So, if Newton were to have chosen $\mathcal{S}$ - then we could ask (in that universe where Newton chose $\mathcal{S}$), why didn't he choose $\int$?

Comment: But the $S$ and its variants have an explanation... I'd accept it easily if Girard would name his system $G$  or even $P$, but $F$ just sounds a bit random. Maybe it is though...